# Rider - Debug docker-compose does not recognize cli options

Tags: docker-compose, rider

I am creating a microservice application using Asp.Net and Angular for university. Until now I never needed to debug the applications and just ran everything through these commands:

```
docker compose down
docker compose build
docker compose up
```

But now I faced a situation where I have to debug. Rider lets me run my docker-compose configuration but when I want to debug it I get the same errors for every microservice (just with different ports):

```
identity_api_1         | Unhandled exception. JetBrains.Util.CommandLineMapper.CommandLineException: Unrecognized option 'urls': '--urls=http://*:7001'
identity_api_1         |    at JetBrains.Util.CommandLineMapper.Impl.AbstractParser.ParseKey(KeyDefinitionSet keyDefinit    ions, RawArgumentIterator rawArgumentIt, IList`1 outParsedArguments)
identity_api_1         |    at JetBrains.Util.CommandLineMapper.Impl.AbstractParser.GetArguments(KeyDefinitionSet keyDef    initions)
identity_api_1         |    at JetBrains.Util.CommandLineMapper.Impl.CommandLineInternal..ctor(ICommandLineParser parser    , KeyDefinitionSet keyDefinitions)
identity_api_1         |    at JetBrains.Util.CommandLineMapper.Impl.CommandLineMapper`1.Map(ICommandLineParser parser)
identity_api_1         |    at JetBrains.Debugger.Worker.DebuggerWorkerMain.<>c.<Main>b__3_0()
identity_api_1         |    at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
```

One service from the docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  identity_api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Identity.Dockerfile
    command: 'dotnet IdentityService.WebAPI.dll --urls=http://*:7001 --environment="Development"'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: identity_database
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: root
    ports:
      - 7001:7001
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - identity_cache
      - identity_database
  
  identity_database:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    
  identity_cache:
    image: redis:6.2.6-alpine
    command: redis-server --loglevel warning
    restart: unless-stopped
```

docker-compose configuration:
[image]

**EDIT:**
When I put the urls-configuration into the appsettings.json, Rider does not recognize the option `environment`

Comment: I did not find any documentation regarding `dotnet --urls=...` - what is this expected to do? Set an environment variable?

Comment: Can you show us your Identity.Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by using `entrypoint:` instead of `command:` in my docker-compose yml file